# -restcomm configuration for Windows

Tags: restcomm

I am beginning to set up on Restcomm Mobicents framework.

In particular I am trying to set up Restcomm on my Windows 8.1 laptop.

Can anyone assist with how to set up RESTCOMM on Windows Server please.  The reason I ask this is that most of the information is presumed to be on Linux, Ubuntu.  Environments like "installation of screen" and also any sample configuration shared are for Ubuntu, Linux environments, but not specifically on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Restcomm is currently prepared to run natively on Linux operating systems, indeed. 
Considering the diversity of OSs and configurations, a Docker image was created to gather everything Restcomm needs to run properly, as an independent layer.

Please check the following links to install Docker in Windows 8.1 and use Restcomm docker image.

About docker: https://www.docker.com/what-docker

Docker installation: http://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/

About Restcomm docker image: http://www.telestax.com/docker-image-for-mobicents-restcomm-7-3-0/

Restcomm docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/gvagenas/restcomm/

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid installing Restcomm on windows, although the simulation will work, when you will have to go live, you will be unable because Windows does not implements the SCTP stack need by Restcomm.