# Error while installing Restcomm Conect

Tags: restcomm

Im trying to install restcomm Connect on windows computer with bash option. As per given  stap on following 2 steps im getting error. Need hint to how to resolve this errors.

Error 1-:
IT@MyPC MINGW64 ~/Restcomm-Connect (master)
$ mkdir $WORKSPACE/dependencies
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/yuliachornobrivets/Restcomm-Connect/dependencies’: No such file or directory

Error- 2
$ chmod +x ./restcomm-connect-build.sh
chmod: cannot access './restcomm-connect-build : No such file or directory

When this error possible and how to resolve.

Comment: Please have a look at this link, i guess this might help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571175/restcomm-configuration-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

Please use Linux or Restcomm docker for starting, we dont have support for windows/mingw now